# Photoshop: Converting text to shape makes them all one color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, shapes

I'm trying to use the Perspective and Distort functions on text, therefore I'm trying to convert the text to shapes in order to accomplish that.

When I did it though, it made all the text one color even though I had set multiple different colors to the letters:

[image]

After selecting "Convert to Shape" from the "Type" menu, I got this:

[image]

[image]

The letters that I had colored differently all changed to the same color. What's the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting text to a shape creates a single shape layer and a single shape layer can only be a single color (bar any effects or overlays etc)...

[image]

If you want distinct shapes with different colors then you need them to be their own shape layers. Simply duplicate your shape layer, change the colors and delete the parts you don't need from each layer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is set to make them all one unified color when you convert to shape.

You can however edit the individual shapes' color afterwards by selecting the letter/shape and changing the color.

Comment: Has this changed in CC (I still use CS6)? As far as I know a single shape layer can only have a single color

Comment: No Cai, it's still the same in CC 2017.  You'd need to have the shapes on different layers to apply a different fill.